# .code16gcc not supported yet (Mac)

Tags: macos, gcc

I want to make for the university a bootloader. For this I have an example .c file and normally it should works. BUT on my Mac I get every time the error message:

```
 My-MacBook-Air:src me$ make start
 rm -f *.bin *.img *.elf *~ *.o *.s
 gcc -m32 -c -g -Os -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror -I. -o os.o os.c
 <inline asm>:1:1: error: unexpected directive .code16gcc
 .code16gcc
 ^
 <inline asm>:1:11: error: .code16gcc not supported yet
 .code16gcc
           ^
 2 errors generated.
 make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Have anyone the same problem and have solved it?
It would be really great!!!!!!!
P.S.: gcc is installed